# Mapping a command not the same as writing command in vim terminal

Tags: command-line, vim, vimrc

I'm trying to use a mapping in my vimrc to execute a command. The command works if I directly type it into the vim terminal, but when I use the same command it stops typing it after the first space. The exact command is:

```
:map <f8> :new | 0read !javac %<CR>
```

When I enter the command manually into vim it gives me a split pain with the output of the compiler which is exactly what I want. However when I hit F8 it just types `:new` and doesn't type anything else. I think the problem is using the spaces in the command. I've tried using quotes around it, and escape characters, but those didn't fix it though. How can I modify my vimrc to get this command to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<bar>` instead of the pipe symbol:

```
:map <f8> :new<bar>0read !javac %<CR>
```